# document.getElementById does not return null, but also does not do what I want. No error in javascript console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

In this instance, I load a single paypal page, in which I am prompted to login.  Once I login, the page changes, through the use of other javascripts on paypal's end.  The address does not change on this transition, nor does the source code in any material way.  I am trying to find a way to have my script wait long enough after the first click to be able to get the element that loads after.  I thought I could do this fairly simple using the following:

```
document.getElementById("submitLogin").click();

window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("continue").click();
};
```

When the script is executed, the first button is clicked, the page transitions, but it won't click the second button that loads.  My javascript console does not report any errors, suggesting that it is able to "get" the element.  Not sure why it won't click it though.

Comment: are you getting "continue" in document.getElementById("continue").id ?

Comment: maybe the `continue` is binded by code and code makes it go somewhere else and when you click is not binded yet.

Comment: OK, I tried the script about 25 more times, on a few occasions, the script did return null for the element "continue", which lends some credence to the theory offered by TheBrain.  It seems as though window.onload does not wait long enough for my purposes.

Comment: Is jQuery not an option? you could do: `$('#submitLogin').click();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If nothing else, you could always poll for the existence of the "continue" element at some interval:

```
function clickContinue() {
    var button = document.getElementById("continue");
    return button ? button.click() : setTimeout(clickContinue, 100);
}

document.getElementById("submitLogin").click();
clickContinue();
```

If you go this route, you'll probably want to include a failsafe so it doesn't run too long, in case something unexpected happens. Something like this should work:

```
clickContinue.interval = 100; // Look for "continue" button every 0.1 second
clickContinue.ttl = 10000; // Approximate time to live: 10 seconds ~ 10,000 ms
clickContinue.tries = clickContinue.ttl / clickContinue.interval | 0;

function clickContinue() {
    var button = document.getElementById("continue"),
        interval = clickContinue.interval;
    return button ? button.click() : 
        clickContinue.tries-- && setTimeout(clickContinue, interval);
}
// ...
```

Take a look at PayPal's API docs and see if they provide a way to set up a callback to handle this, though. This polling technique should probably only be used as a last resort.

Comment: Well, that certainly worked.  Thank you so much, Dagg Nabbit!  All of you are a lovely bunch.  Sadly, I've been trying for days to solve a problem you solved in 5 minutes.  Thanks again.

Comment: Well, try to find another way to solve it anyway if you can, this is sort of a last-ditch resort. ;)